Kitchenaid dishwasher leaking from front left corner
Kitchenaid KDTM404ESS3 is leaking from the front left corner.
Door gasket replaced.  Soap dispenser replaced.
Removed kick plate and sound dampener foam, with a mirror and flashlight I can see water coming from the left door latch area, right by the front left corner of the basin.
Dishwasher is level side to side and (we think) front to back.
I’m stumped!  Any ideas, of gurus of the stack-exchange?

is it cycle related? like pumping out

Even though it appears level, try raising the front a bit, just a cm or two.

I had same problem and it turned out to not be level, front-to-back.

Thanks for replies.  One of the legs looks nearly maxed out, but I’ll try to see if have a turn or two left tonight.  If not, maybe I can shim them a little bit.
Jimmy, where did you put the level to measure front/back?

I checked front/Back level tonight and it was good.  Then raised the front slightly to see if that would make a difference.  It leaked again from same spot 10 minutes into a 57 minute express wash.  It seemed to be in the third cycle, but we don’t know what the cycles mean.  Basically the third time the sound changed.

Any other ideas?  I hate to have the repair guy out again he did nothing last time and charged us $150!
